# Ordering a <li> element using 'like'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of data returned by a javascript query (code shown below). This is returned by Github so one of the fields shows the dominant language used in the project. Can I make a sorted list of the items with their own headers, returned by identifying all the unique primary languages used in my repo?

```
function outputPageContent() {
   if (repositories.length == 0) {
      outhtml = outhtml + '<p>No repos!</p></div>';
   } else {
      outhtml = outhtml + '<p><strong>Project List:</strong></p> <ul>';
      $.each(repositories, function(index) {
         outhtml = outhtml + '<li id="' + repositories[index].language + index + '"><a href="' + repositories[index].html_url + '" target="_blank">' + repositories[index].name + '</a></li>';
      });
      outhtml = outhtml + '</ul></div>';
   }
   $('#ghapidata').html(outhtml);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort before create your html.

```
repositories.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
})
```

Sort function can get a compare function also. This anonymous function that defines an alternative sort order. You can change the comparison indexes of your array.

**Full Code**

```
function outputPageContent() {
   if (repositories.length == 0) {
      outhtml = outhtml + '<p>No repos!</p></div>';
   } else {
      outhtml = outhtml + '<p><strong>Project List:</strong></p> <ul>';
      repositories.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      })
      $.each(repositories, function(index) {
         outhtml = outhtml + '<li id="' + repositories[index].language + index + '"><a href="' + repositories[index].html_url + '" target="_blank">' + repositories[index].name + '</a></li>';
      });
      outhtml = outhtml + '</ul></div>';
   }
   $('#ghapidata').html(outhtml);
}
```

**Alternative Sort Method**

Also you can use more fluent another compare function.

```
repositories.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
})
```

Comment: you could directly use inside your sort  `return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);`

Comment: Thanks @quirimmo I wil add this to the answer.